# How to select rows which are mapped to a junction table in a many to many relationship?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have three tables:

- `locations` (has `zipcode`, `location name`);
- `professionals` (has `name`);
- `location_professional`.

I want to select only those rows from `locations` table where `professional_id` is 4. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `locations` and `professionals` also have their PK columns as `location_id` and `professional_id`, respectively, and `location_professional` uses those columns to link the two entities:

```
SELECT loc.*
    FROM location_professional AS lp
    JOIN locations AS loc  ON lp.location_id = loc.location_id
    WHERE lp.professional_id = 4;
```

In your simple example, there is no need to also `JOIN professionals AS p ON ...`.  In a typical case, that would also be needed.